# How can I detect that my Node.js script is being terminated by forever?

Tags: javascript, node.js, signals, exit, forever

I have a node script which launches child processes. I want to make sure they are all terminated when my script is terminated, whether it terminates normally (there should be no child processes left to kill) or not (this is where I expect to have to do something).

I thought of using `process.on('exit', fn)`, but I noticed that `fn` is not called when my script was launched by [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) (`forever myScript.js`). It **is** called however when I run my script normally (`node myScript.js`).

I proceeded to try to find a signal I could listen for, but none of the following seem to be fired: `SIGUSR1`, `SIGTERM`, `SIGPIPE`, `SIGHUP`, `SIGTERM`, `SIGINT`, `SIGBREAK`, `SIGWINCH`

I also tried with `process.on('beforeExit', ...)` but that is also not fired.

Here is the script I am using to test this (just imagine that instead of logging some text I would kill any remaining child processes):

**myScript.js**

```
console.log('started')

process.on('beforeExit', function () {
  console.log('beforeExit fired')
})
process.on('exit', function () {
  console.log('exit fired')
})

// signals
process.on('SIGUSR1', function () {
  console.log('SIGUSR1 fired')
  process.exit(1)
})
process.on('SIGTERM', function () {
  console.log('SIGTERM fired')
  process.exit(1)
})
process.on('SIGPIPE', function () {
  console.log('SIGPIPE fired')
})
process.on('SIGHUP', function () {
  console.log('SIGHUP fired')
  process.exit(1)
})
process.on('SIGTERM', function () {
  console.log('SIGTERM fired')
  process.exit(1)
})
process.on('SIGINT', function () {
  console.log('SIGINT fired')
  process.exit(1)
})
process.on('SIGBREAK', function () {
  console.log('SIGBREAK fired')
})
process.on('SIGWINCH', function () {
  console.log('SIGWINCH fired')
})

// Let's keep the process open long enough to kill it manually
setTimeout(function () {}, 5000)
```

Let's try it out by launching the script and killing it with `Ctrl-C` before the 5 seconds are up. First "normally":

```
$ node index.js
started
^CSIGINT fired
exit fired
$
```

This behaves how I expect it should. Now let's try with forever:

```
$ forever index.js
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
started
^C
$
```

Different behaviour.

Comment: I'm pretty sure forever doesn't hook up stdin to the node process, so it's not getting the exit -- you'll need to stop it with `forever stop index.js`. Check the forever logs, by default in `~/.forever/<random_string>` -- also, `forever list` to list running, monitored processes and their logfile.

Comment: @furydevoid `forever list` doesn't list my process.  Also there is no `~/.forever/<random_string>`. Try it for yourself with the code above.

Comment: Oh, and `forever stop` expects a pid, not a file name

Answer (score 2):

When you send cntl-C from the command line, `forever` gets a SIGINT. You're blowing up `forever`, not your program directly, so I wouldn't necessarily expect that your program gets to run it's `exit` event handler.

If you change your `setTimeout` to blow up your program (e.g., `setTimeout(function () { undefined(); }, 500)`) then you will see that the `exit` event handler does in fact run. They key is that the `TypeError` introduced in that line of code (where it's trying to treat `undefined` like a function) kills your program but does not kill forever.

Similarly, if your program exits gracefully, the `exit` event fires as well, even when the program is started with `forever`.

So I think you can expect `process.on('exit');` to fire even if your program is being started and monitored by `forever` as long as `forever` itself doesn't terminate unexpectedly. (It's only a problem if it terminates unexpectedly. If `forever` gracefully stops your program, say with `forever stop`, then that won't be a problem. The `exit` event will fire.)

Comment: When forever fails unexpectedly, my process also terminates right? Is there no way to detect that? Or does my process perhaps survive forever being terminated?

Comment: I think you would have to add SIG event handlers in forever, that would send the same signal to the child process (your script), when received

Comment: Perhaps relevant from the Node.js issue tracker: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2853